# What's the deal with this ducking duck?

Tags: bug

Not sure how unique it is to Academia.SE but it didn't show up in MathOverflow. To get rid of it, I had to click on it which involved giving it access to the microphone. How do I know this website has relinquished this access after I dismissed the duck? I think the duck should go or at least be presented in a more informed way, with opt-in, not opt-out.

Comment: And tomorrow is 1st of April, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I guess I fell for it.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch It comes up on MathStackExchange even though I no longer have an account there. Yay for MO exceptionalism, I guess

Comment: If you have ublock, the following rules `stackexchange.com##.c-pointer.js-quack-btn:nth-of-type(1) > g > path:nth-of-type(3)
stackexchange.com##.js-step01.js-step.step.ws-nowrap.p12
stackexchange.com##.c-pointer.js-quack-btn:nth-of-type(1)
stackexchange.com##.quack-popover--arrow
 ` will hide the duck

Comment: Why do you hate the duck? He is helping me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

**The duck *never* accesses your microphone**, even if you say that you have one.

Think about it: If it could access your microphone without a browser-site confirmation, so could every other website, which would be a privacy nightmare.

[Further reading on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308581/255554).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it on multiple sites, so that suggests this needs to be brought up on [the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com).